# YouTube Data API for Get My Videos return authError

Tags: java, android, youtube

> Http URL Connection Code for hitting YouTube Data API

```
{
URL u = new URL(url);
    //Set up the Connection
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Android-Package", "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Android-Cert", "C3:E3:59:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"); connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer ya29.GlsaBQ2iHUUHtf_PInfsjmdKOKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.connect();
    }

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
}
```

> Respose of the api:-
>
> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "errors": [
>             {
>                 "domain": "global",
>                 "reason": "authError",
>                 "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>                 "locationType": "header",
>                 "location": "Authorization"
>             }
>         ],
>         "code": 401,
>         "message": "Invalid Credentials"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Apis that are not required authToken working fine like get Videos by id ,get PlayListItems,Playlists of channel etc.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred due to "Authorization" parameter of header with "Bearer" authCode,if you are using goole login authcode than you should have convert your google login authCode to Bearer authcode and after that pass it to header with Authorization key than it should work fine.